# Identifying connector for 12v trigger

Tags: audio, video

I'm getting a projector ([http://www.amazon.com/Optoma-HD26-1080p-Theater-Projector/dp/B00LL2SHK6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LL2SHK6)) with a 12v trigger so that I can lower a screen with it. I need a cord that will connect the 12v trigger to the "screen" connection in this picture. Can anyone help with the name of the cord that I need? [picture of the wall plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/073tL.jpg).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell because the pic is a little blurry, but it looks like what's called a barrel connector (if I'm seeing correctly that it's a ring with a pin in the middle.  if it's actually a hole (not a pin), then it's probably an RCA connector).  You can pick up a barrel connector at a local hobby shop, or cut one that fits off an old power adapter if you're desperate.

According to the manual, the connection on the projector is a 3.5mm plug where the sleeve is ground and the ring is your signal.  You'd have to check your screen to see what kind of signal it's expecting. Looks like someone may have wired it up in a custom way to a wall plate, so you might be looking at a custom cable.

I googled a bit for a 3.5mm to barrel connector, but it's hard to tell what size connector you need, and they all seem to be for custom applications.

From the look of it, I'd guess someone custom made a cable that would connect to that wall plate.  If you have basic soldering skills, or know someone who does it should be pretty simple.

Comment: This is very helpful!  It is a ring with a pin in the middle.  I'm going to look for barrel connectors now and see what I can make work.  I'm under the impression that the original owner of the house put in all of this wiring so I'm not surprised that it looks custom.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, remember to check it as the accepted answer.